# How to get a view of a memory mapped file in Linux

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, linux-kernel, mmap

I am memory mapping a large (4GB) file in Linux for sequential read-only access.  I use mmap() for creating output buffers, but this is the first time I have used it to map an input file.

I know how to map the file, but I don't know how reads are handled with a file that is too large for memory.  My understanding is that if I try to access a part of the file that is not loaded into memory, the OS will page fault, then read the next 4096 bytes.  But I don't want a page fault for every 4096 bytes.

I have seen references to "views" of an mmap file, but I haven't found anything in Linux about how to map the next view.  For example, if I initially have a view of 10MB, when I reach the end I want to map the next view of 10MB.

Windows has a MapViewOfFile function.  My question is how to map a view of a file in Linux, and how to map the next view when the current view is finished.  I have used mprotect with output buffers -- could I just mprotect the next X bytes of data and unprotect the previous protection?

Comment: Look into `posix_madvise()`

Comment: @Shawn -- Thanks for your comment.  I was just reading the Linux man page on madvise, and it looked like the answer I needed.

Comment: Is there any reason I should use posix_madvise() over madvise()?  From reading the man pages, they look basically the same.

Comment: Portability so it's easier to run on non Linux operating systems.

Comment: *"For example, if I initially have a view of 10MB, when I reach the end I want to map the next view of 10MB."* - this is already more or less what Linux does and it's called readahead. You basically never need to fault every single page because of readahead. Without this approach everything in the system would be an order of magnitude slower.

Comment: How does the OS know how much to read at a time?  Is it optimized to the amount of free contiguous space?  Is posix_madvise optional?

Comment: Readahead happens regardless of `madvise`/`fadvise`, but of course you can make it more efficient with such syscalls. There's also the `readahead` syscall. See [this LWN article](https://lwn.net/Articles/897786/) for the default readahead semantics.

Comment: I just posted an updated question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77587020/linux-how-to-increase-the-readahead-size-for-mmapped-files