# Linux: how to increase the readahead size for mmapped files

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management, posix, memory-mapped-files

I am memory mapping (with mmap) a large (4GB) file in Linux for sequential read-only access.

When I read data from the mapping, I know that the OS faults in a certain number of pages into the page cache.  From my research, it appears that the amount that is read (the readahead) is fairly small -- around 64K to 512K (see https://lwn.net/Articles/897786/).

For example, when I run "sudo fdisk --list /dev/sda1" for my 2TB ssd. the optimal I/O size is 33553920 bytes:

sudo fdisk --list /dev/sda1
Disk /dev/sda1: 1.84 TiB, 2000365363200 bytes, 3906963600 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 33553920 bytes

So I think I would be advised to increase to the reported optimal size, especially because I am mapping a 4GB file.  But how to do that?  Could I use blockdev for that?  Would a larger readahead improve performance or not?

I plan to use posix_madvise.  If I do that, will the readhead size automatically be adjusted to the amount specified in the posix_madvise call?

Thanks.

Comment: It's my experience that these things need to be benchmarked for your particular workload. If you could universally speed up all applications by adjusting the readahead size, then Linux would already do so. (Do be sure to madvice it as sequential though)